# What's the difference between HSV and grayscale intensities?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, rgb, grayscale, hsv

I'm doing some research on image processing using MATLAB and I've created grayscale intensity images in two different ways using `rgb2gray` and `rgb2hsv` like so:

```
read_image = imread(handles.myImage);
bc_gambar2 = imresize(read_image,[280 540]); 
g = rgb2gray(bc_gambar2);  % First intensity image
g2 = rgb2hsv(bc_gambar2); 
g = g2(:,:,3);             % Second intensity image
```

The result seems better using `rgb2hsv` and indexing than using `rgb2gray`. Can anybody tell me what the difference is and why it's happening?

Here's a sample image I'm using (if needed):

[image: example manuscript image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calculation used by [`rgb2hsv`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2hsv.html) to compute the value (i.e. lightness) channel is different than that used by [`rgb2gray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2gray.html) to compute the grayscale intensity. They are described by [the second and fourth bullet points here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Lightness), respectively. Briefly:

- The computation for the value channel (`rgb2hsv`) is:

  ```
  g = max(bc_gambar2, [], 3);
  ```
- The computation for the grayscale intensity (`rgb2gray`) is:

  ```
  g = 0.299.*bc_gambar2(:, :, 1) + ...
      0.587.*bc_gambar2(:, :, 2) + ...
      0.114.*bc_gambar2(:, :, 3);
  ```

More information about different color spaces can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_space).

Comment: pardon me mates, but can you describing using image so i can more understand about big different between 

g = max(bc_gambar2, [], 3); & rgb2gray?

if from the link that you give me i can conclude that's because rgb2gray its only making process for red,green,blue colour whereas hsv is processing red,green,blue and also cyan,yellow,magnetta colour..thats right mates?

Comment: @jethow: `rgb2gray` is removing all color information and creating a grayscale intensity image that approximates the intensity of the color image. `rgb2hsv` is simply converting from one [color space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_space0 model to another. It's a way of representing color that uses a hue (index into a standard HSV color map), saturation (amount of color present), and value (intensity scaling).

Comment: 'rgb2hsv is simply converting from one [color space](en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_space0 model to another'

which color space that converted? for default is blue?
or its depend on my image source mates?

Comment: @jethow: I messed up the link in my comment. Here's the correct one: [Color space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_space). You should really read through it. I don't understand what you mean by "default is blue".

Comment: after read some article i found the points of HSV colour structure, and i got it what you told me before...thanks for the reply mates :)